# What's the equivalent to not using params with Expression<Func<>>[]?

Tags: entity-framework-6, func

I have some code in a repository base class for Entity Framework that eager loads Navigation properties:

```
public virtual List<T> Find(Func<T, bool> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
//blah biddy blah blah
}
```

Then when calling the above method:

```
var beers = BeerRepository.Find(x => x.Type == "IPA", a => a.Ingredients, b => b.Sizes, c => c.Hangovers);
```

It works great.  I know that using "params" provides a great magic shortcut when calling the method and I've seen some SIMPLE examples of what would be needed without it.

But, I'm having trouble figuring out how to call the method above when I remove params from the signature.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic method is a method *template*. If you supply a type argument, it becomes a concrete, typed, method. Your method (without `params`)...

```
public virtual List<T> Find<T>(Func<T, bool> where, 
      Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
```

...in `BeerRepository` will turn into something like...

```
public virtual List<Beer> Find(Func<Beer, bool> where, 
      Expression<Func<Beer, object>>[] navigationProperties)
```

...which clearly shows you have to provide a `Expression<Func<Beer, object>>[]` array. It takes a bit more clunky code to build that, because you can't take advantage of type inference:

```
var navProps = new Expression<Func<Beer, object>>[]
               {
                   a => a.Ingredients,
                   a => a.Sizes,
                   a => a.Hangovers
               });
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hung up on how removing "params" removes the type inference. I would've up voted, but, apparently I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question.

You can just call

```
beerRepository.Find((x => x.Type == "IPA")
```

And then inside Find() you'll see that the navigationProperties array will be empty.